# Use coroutines to make a function return a value obtained in a callback

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I'm fairly new to async development and specially coroutines. What I'm saying is basically that I don't even know if what I'm trying to achieve is possible or not.

I have a method called `sendAudioMessage` that I want to return a string. Here is the (obfuscated) code:

```
override suspend fun sendAudioMessage(): String {
   // ... Do some stuff
   val listener: WebSocketUtils.Listener = object: WebSocketUtils.Listener {
      // ... some (not relevant) functions
      override fun onDisconnect(code: Int, reason: String?) {
         //Do some stuff
         return "myResult -> $code" //This obviously doesn't compile since is trying to make onDisconnect return a string instead of Unit
      }
   }
}
```

And then I want to call that like this:

```
override fun send(request: String) {
    CoroutineScope(IO).launch {
        val response = d.sendAudioMessage()
        analyzeResponse( response, request )
    }
}
```

Is this even possible? If so, how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to wrap your callbacks inside a `suspendCancellableCoroutine` block in order to turn your blocking API call into a suspending function, so you can call it from a coroutine. It works like this:

```
suspend fun sendAudioMessage(): String = suspendCancellableCoroutine { continuation ->
    WebSocketUtils.Listener {
        // ... some (not relevant) functions
        override fun onDisconnect(code: Int, reason: String?) {
            //Do some stuff
            when (code) {
                OK -> continuation.resume("myResult -> $code")
                ERROR -> continuation.resumeWithException(Exception(reason))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When your API call returns successfully you can return the result to your coroutine calling `continuation.resume` with the result as argument.

When your API call returns with an error you can throw an exception calling `continuation.resumeWithException`.

Now you can call `sendAudioMessage` inside a coroutine and work with its result as usual:

```
class MyClass: CoroutineScope by CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default) {
    
    ...
    
    override fun send(request: String) {
        launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            val response = d.sendAudioMessage()
            analyzeResponse(response, request)
        }
    }
    
    ...
}
```

Comment: Yes, the situation I recall running into was a callback that could fire multiple times, but we only wanted the first result. So in the callback we cancel the request and resume the continuation with the result. But further calls of the callback may have already been queued so you have to guard the `resume` call because the continuation is no longer active. I might be remembering details incorrectly. Anyway, I'll delete my comments since it isn't relevant.

Comment: @Tenfour04 This code: `job.cancel(); cont!!.also { cont -> println("cont.isActive? ${cont.isActive}"); cont.resume("result") }` prints `cont.isActive? false` but doesn't throw an exception. There is actually no dedicated check that would resolve whether it has already been resumed. But, checking `isActive` does also prevent you from double resumption so it's good enough of a check.