# How to convert custom callback to coroutine

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I am using Stripe library which provides me with custom callback functionality.

I want a custom callback convert to Kotlin coroutine

Here is the code

```
   override fun retrievePaymentIntent(clientSecret: String): Flow<Resource<PaymentIntent>> = flow{
        emit(Resource.Loading())
        Terminal.getInstance().retrievePaymentIntent(clientSecret,
            object : PaymentIntentCallback {
                override fun onFailure(e: TerminalException) {}

                override fun onSuccess(paymentIntent: PaymentIntent) {
                    emit(Resource.Success(paymentIntent))
                }
            })
    }
```

The problem is I can't call emit function inside onSuccess/onFailure. The error shown in the picture.

[image]

Is it possible to change something here to make it work or how could I convert custom callback to coroutine?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63833665/use-coroutines-to-make-a-function-return-a-value-obtained-in-a-callback/63834418#63834418) might help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`suspendCancellableCoroutine`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/suspend-cancellable-coroutine.html?query=inline%20suspend%20fun%20%3CT%3E%20suspendCancellableCoroutine(crossinline%20block:%20(CancellableContinuation%3CT%3E)%20-%3E%20Unit):%20T) to model your callback-based one-shot request like so:

```kotlin
suspend fun retrievePaymentIntent(clientSecret: String): PaymentIntent =
    suspendCancellableCoroutine { continuation ->
        Terminal.getInstance().retrievePaymentIntent(clientSecret,
            object : PaymentIntentCallback {
                override fun onFailure(e: TerminalException)
                {
                    continuation.resumeWithException(e)
                }

                override fun onSuccess(paymentIntent: PaymentIntent)
                {
                    continuation.resume(paymentIntent)
                }
            })

        continuation.invokeOnCancellation { /*cancel the payment intent retrieval if possible*/ }
    }
```